# Wait for user interaction before finishing onCreate()

Tags: android, asynchronous, oncreate, program-flow

In my app I set everything up in **onCreate** and then, start an Async Task which sets about loading all of my resources etc... just after the Async Task starts, I add my splash screen to my layout.  When everything has loaded, the splashscreen is dismissed and my Open GL Renderer is revealed underneath.

What I'm attempting to do, is to add a dialog screen (basically, another **View** class that displays a bitmap).  And, I *don't want* any of the Splash stuff to happen until the user presses taps the screen within my dialog screen.

It would be something like this (Note, this is just an excerpt from my real onCreate but should be enough to illustrate the problem)

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        SplashScreen splash = new SplashScreen (getApplication(), width, height);
        ConsentDialog consentDialog = new ConsentDialog(getApplication(), width, height);

        //Add the consent dialog
        layout.addView(consentDialog);

        setContentView(layout);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Splashscreen
        backgroundResources = new MyAsync(newBundle);
        backgroundResources.execute(); 
        layout.addView(splash);
}
```

However when I run the above, it shows the splash screen, loads everything, then dismisses the splash, leaving the dialog behind.

How can I pause (or something that gives the effect of being paused), the onCreate method just after setContentView until the user has tapped the screen? (Note, I'm waiting for touch event using the onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) method in my consentDialog object.

Basically, the async shouldn't start *until* the user taps the screen.  If this can't be done, What could I do to achieve something that would give the effect I desire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I pause (or something that gives the effect of being paused), the onCreate method just after setContentView until the user has pressed a key?

You don't.

> Note, I'm waiting for a keypress using the onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) method in my consentDialog object

Put your work that should wait "until the user taps the screen" logic in `onTouch()`, or in a method invoked from `onTouch()`.

Answer (score 1):

At the point onCreate, app doesn't actually active (seeable or interactive) to the user.

I think all you can do is just wait for the user's interaction (tapping) before showing splash.

Activity is event-driven. You should set (add) onClickListener or onTouchListener to your screen View. And in the implementation of listener you may write code showing splash. This code will be invoked only when the user taps.